# React async action dispatching

Tags: reactjs

In my react application, I faced to a problem with async await with actions.

This is my code.

```
    export const createOrUpdateProfile = (profileData, history) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    dispatch(setProfileLoading());         
    await axios.post('/api/profile', profileData);
    history.push('/dashboard');
  } catch(error) {
    dispatch(profileError(GET_ERRORS, error.response.data));
  }
}
```

The problem is the loading spinner is shown after a short delay. I set `loading` (a bool) to true with `setProfileLoading()`. When the dashboard is loading, then only the spinner is shown based on the `profileLoading` boolean.

But before navigating to the dashboard, an async action is dispatched to create the profile:

```
await axios.post('/api/profile', profileData);
```

Then only the navigation happens:

```
history.push('/dashboard');
```

What I did to overcome this was I put the `history.push('/dashboard')` call before the async operation. Am I doing this right? Navigating before making the API call seems a little odd. Can someone help me on this?

```
export const createOrUpdateProfile = (profileData, history) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    dispatch(setProfileLoading());
    history.push('/dashboard');
    await axios.post('/api/profile', profileData);
  } catch(error) {
    dispatch(profileError(GET_ERRORS, error.response.data));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, why are you not making the API call in your dashboard component's `componentDidMount` method itself. I am asking because if someone directly lands on '/dashboard' url, how will the data gets populated in your use case?

Comment: Im in the createProfile component. When the component is created, it goes to the dashboard. Dashboard has the loader in the componentDidMount

Comment: Ok. So if you route first and then make an API call, what would happen if API call fails? What is rendered on Dashboard.